# Why this alert doesn't work using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, alert, sweetalert

I'm working on ASP.NET and on the view I have a code like this, If I use the sweet alert outside the function it works, and If I change the sweet alert in to a regular alert it works too but It doesn't work like the code below. (I also have the script with the library on the view)

```html
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return foo();" />

<script type="text/javascript">      
       function foo() {
       swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success")
       return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: swal can not prevent the button from running. That is no "wait" in JavaScript. So it can not act like windlow.alert()

Comment: well obviously, you are missing function; what is swal?

Comment: @MilanRilexRistic it is a commonly used library that makes a dialog. It is the last tag.

Comment: @epascarello so how can I run a Swal into an input type submit

Comment: ok, you forgot to include library js and css

Comment: Code is working fine I edited the snippet see

Comment: @MaheerAli , editing the code in question to make it work defeats the purpose of the question and is confusing to future visitors.

Comment: @HeribertoLugo It has NOTHING TO DO with the scripts not being included. lol The OP has it in their code and it is working.... It is the fact it is in a form and the form submits.... So rolling it back was the wrong thing to do with the edit....

Comment: @epascarello the includes were not in the code originally posted. i didnt see where he stated his issue was the post. he just said "it dont work", and the neccessary libraries were not included. so therefore it did not work..

Comment: @epascarello but i definitely see where you are coming from. i voted you up, but its still not clear if that was his issue or he forgot to include the libraries. he himself said "these all work".. commenting on the solution that just did a library include. new issue is they work too fast lol

Comment: OP edited to add it and someone removed it. My very first comment saw the issue without the library code. Guessing no one read it while I started o make the answer.

Comment: no.. the person who added it removed it because of the comment i made.. but re-reading his question 10 times, i think you are right to assume its the post not working. your solution should be marked as the answer. nice job!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the submit button, it is submitting a form.

With an alert, it blocks the browser so the code will wait until you push okay and than submit the form. But the issue when you move to use sweet alert, you can not block the browser action. So you will have to cancel the click and submit the form manually.

```js
// called onclick of the submit button
function foo() {
  swal("foo")
    .then(function() {
      // manually submit the form
      document.getElementById("yourFormId").submit()
    });
  return false; // cancel the button click
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<form id="yourFormId">

  <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return foo();" />

</form>
```

Comment: This answer and the other works fine, but the sweet alert pop up really fast

Comment: So theres no way to show the full sweet alert in a submit?

Comment: Wowzers.... read my answer. You have to cancel the button click and manually submit the form using sweet alerts callback.

Comment: I edited my answer with a working example with the form being submitted after you click on the swal button. This shows you how to cancel the submit button click, and than submit the form when you are ready. If you are planning on making it a "are you sure" than you need to use the value passed in to either submit or cancel it.

Answer (score 3):

ok, you forgot to include library js and css

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    
    
    


<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return foo();" />

<script type="text/javascript">      
       function foo() {
       swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success")
       return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works, but it is super fast. Is it a way to fix that?

Comment: If you click full page after running the snippet you'll notice it seems to work as expected.

Comment: NO it will submit the form! It is not correct. lol.... The issue is not the the OP did not include the library code....

Comment: How is a wrong answer upvoted 3 times.... lol A submit button in a form submits. The page will submit so the message will not be there....